# How to keep a NodeJS Cloud Compute VM online?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am trying to create a Discord bot that is online 24/7. It's purpose is to listen for messages in a Discord server, check a database then return a response

I start the VM by using Cloud Shell and running these commands

```
node main.js &
pm2 start pm2config.json
pm2 startup
pm2 save
```

This brings the bot online and everything works as it should. The problem comes when I exit the terminal, then some time later the bot will go offline and will not respond to any messages. I am trying to use `pm2` to fix this but it doesn't seem to be working. The instance is running in the compute console

When I try to run the same commands in the SSH terminal, it says `-bash: npm: command not found`, I am not sure why or how to install npm on a compute instance, but any help is very much appreciated!

`pm2config.json`

```
{
    "apps": [{
      "script" : "./main.js",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production",
        "PORT": "8080"
      }
    }]
  }
```

Comment: I am not sure I am getting the question, on the first part you stated that you have already got the Discord bot up and running, then after connecting via SSH it is not even installed?  Check this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  to make the question better and provide all the details you can give.

Comment: So it ended up being that Cloud Shell and the actual instance VM are different things. I am guessing I had node, pm2 and all the code on the debug VM and was not working on the actual VM. Just so I can be very clear, on a brand new VM instance there should be nothing installed, not even node correct? I had to install node by running a command in the terminal first. I am using Linux I think

Comment: Correct, if you will be using the cloud shell to initiate that command for your node, make sure you have already initiated SSH on your VM instance. Or you can just use the [SSH button](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#connecting_to_a_linux_vm_instance) on the VM Instance itself just to be sure.